# Android deeplink calling again and again when app is not running in background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, deep-linking, android-deep-link

when my app is running in background and i open using deeplink i will open perticular screen and a the end it will open browser . if i open my app again from recent app it will working fine but if my app is not running in background and i open my app using deep link then it will follow same process and the end it will redirect to browser but when I open my app from recent app again it will perform deeplink task again

deeplink associated activity oncreate called again

i what to not permorm deeplink again

Comment: Share some code, also check your `onNewIntent()` code

Comment: provide the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)